# How can I use a MI424WR-GEN2 as a Wireless Access Point?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a Verizon-branded Actiontec MI424WR-GEN2 Wireless router. I already have a firewall/router at my network's perimeter. How can I attach the MI424WR-GEN2 as a second wireless access point for my home network?

Answer (score 0):

Several steps are needed:

1. Under `Firewall Settings -> General`, set the firewall to `Minimum Security (Low)`:
   [image]
2. Under `Firewall Settings -> Remote administration`, set check the box for `Allow Incoming WAN Access to Web-Management` -> `Using Primary HTTP Port (80)`. Also check both boxes under `Diagnostic Tools`:

[image]

3. Under `My Network -> Network Connections`, click on edit for the first entry, then click `Settings`:

[image]

Then, ensure `Internet Protocol` is set to `Obtain an IP Address Automatically`, `DNS Server` is set to `Obtain DNS Server Address Automatically`, and `IP Address Distribution` is set to `Disabled`

[image]

5. Under `Wireless Settings -> Basic Security Settings`, set the SSID to the same name as your other Access Point:

[image]

6. Under `Wireless Settings -> Advanced Security Settings`, set the security to WPA2 and set a password

Loose reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mc3-AKm7yaY